# Zipping json response in Java and unzipping in React

Tags: java, reactjs

I am trying to zip json string and trying to unzip it in react js, but unzipping is not working for
me.

### My Java webservice is spring rest application, my dao layer is receiving json string,  i am converting into gzip with below method

```
public static String compress(String str)throws IOException{
ByteArrayOutputStreamString out= gzip=new GZIPOUtputstream();
gzip.write(str.getBytes());
gzip.close();
String outStr=out.toString("UTF-8");
return outStr;
}
```

---

### My controller returns this zipped response back to client

```
    @RequestMapping(value="reports" method=RequestMethod.POST,produces= 
    {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
    public @ResponseBody String myMethod(@RequestHeader("service") String service,@RequestBody 
    String request){
    String response=null;
    try{
        resonse=dao call
       }
    catch(Exception e){
    }
    return response;
  }
```

---

Can anyone please let me know how to unzip this response in react js, i am using axios to access
java webservice in my react code

Comment: What is stopping you from using [spring's inbuild feature](https://stacktips.com/tutorials/spring-boot/enable-gzip-compression-for-spring-boot-response), and let the browser handle decompression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Ensure Spring Api return MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE
- Use pako as a dependency in react
- Send request as blob and read it with file reader

Based on

https://muthuishere.medium.com/send-compressed-data-from-spring-boot-uncompress-read-in-reactjs-6b14dfdb17e4

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was struggling for weeks.

Comment: @BiswarupSen do rate it and accept it as valid answer, if it solved your question